# AsteriskNOW в DomU на xen

Tags: centos, asterisk, xen

Пытаюсь установить *AsteriskNOW* в *DomU* на гипервизоре *xen*. Скачал с оф. сайта *ISO*-образ. *Xen* у меня на *LVM* работает. Создал *lvm*-раздел, форматировал его в *ext3*, также как и другие разделы отформатированы.

Написал конфиг:

```
import os
host_uname = os.uname()[2]

name = "AsteriskNOW"
builder = "hvm"
memory = "1024"
disk = ['phy:/dev/VolGroup00/Asterisk,ioemu:sda,w','phy:/dev/cdrom,ioemu:hdc:cdrom,r']
vif = ['type=ioemu,bridge=avpublic']
device_model = "/usr/lib64/xen/bin/qemu-dm"
kernel = "/usr/lib/xen/boot/hvmloader"
vnc=1
boot="d"
vcpus=1
serial = "pty"
on_reboot = 'destroy'
on_crash = 'destroy'
```

Подключаюсь по *vnc*, выбираю [Full inslall](http://i2.imageban.ru/out/2015/09/28/ebb6a9185fdfc1d27fa29097ceba3de6.jpg), он [прогружается](http://i4.imageban.ru/out/2015/09/28/d864012a7850b62f45da587163f309cd.jpg), и дальше выдаёт [ошибку](http://i5.imageban.ru/out/2015/09/28/65551d84dc4c4b28b065d10a7a7e8d75.jpg).

Не понятно, какой именно драйвер нужен: от жесткого или от сетевой карты, так как там в списке (*Select Driver*) есть и то и то. Но, что бы ни выбрал, не помогает. Да думаю, этого не должно быть вообще. У меня у всех *DomU* в конфигах указан именно *avpublic*.

Comment: возможно, «криво» собран intird в iso-образе, а может быть не стоит использовать ioemu для диска и сетевой карты. // а дистрибутивный asterisk вас чем-то не устраивает?

Comment: Насчет криво собранного initrd не знаю, но я видел кучу примеров в инете установки без xen, и там все нормально устанавливалось. Насчет ioemu, а что использовать тогда, у меня опыта в этомделе нет. И еще, забыл написать, [тут](http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?p=211496) есть ответ по идее, но я так и не понял, как можно изменить, поменял avpublic на eth0, так _create Asterisk.hvm_ зависает при этом параметре. А с avpublic всё нормально сразу грузится. Может кто-нибудь лучше поймёт что там помогло исправить эту ошибку? Насчет дистрибутивного тоже вариант, если этот не пойдет. Но пока так.

Comment: *Насчет криво собранного initrd* — варианты: 1. слишком древний. 2. выбросили то, что посчитали «лишним». *ioemu, а что использовать* — для сети, вроде бы, только два варианта: ioemu и vif. для диска — не в курсе.

Comment: Понятно, так а по ссылке что я указал смотрели, так вроде ответ, не?

Comment: по ссылке информация про *virtualbox*. не знаю, чем она может быть вам полезна.

Comment: Да, я знаю, там VBox, но ошибка та же, возможно на VBox и xen похожие механизмы. Только я не до конца понял, какое там решение. То ли нужно название моста поменять в самом xen то ли в конфиге? Это конечно не 100%, но вполне может быть, что решение такое же.

Comment: Вообще там (по ссылке) команда, которая указывет интерфейс хостовой машины, который будет использоваться виртуалкой для моста. Так там указывается eth0. И говорится, что проблема именно названии, я так понял? Только что мне то сделать нужно не понятно пока.